# Sign in with Google - detect if triggered by user

Tags: google-signin

I have implemented "Sign in with Google" using Javascript (https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/sign-in). The sign-in button is shown as follows:

```
<div class="g-signin2" data-onsuccess="onSignIn"></div>

function onSignIn(googleUser) { ... }
```

When the user is already signed-in then the `onSignIn` function is immediately triggered when the page is loaded. Is there a way to detect whether the function is triggered automatically (when the page is loaded), or as a result of a user manually logging in?

Regards,

Comment: You can set a click listener to `.g-signin2` and set a variable to true if the button is clicked on. Else, you can assume that the user automatically logged in.

Comment: Works great. Please post this as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set a click listener to `.g-signin2` and set a variable to true if the button is clicked on. Else, you can assume that the user automatically logged in.

jQuery

```
var isButtonClicked = false;
$('.g-signin2').click(function() {
  isButtonClicked = true;
});
```

JavaScript

```
var isButtonClicked = false;
document.querySelector('.g-signin2').addEventListener('click', function() {
   isButtonClicked = true;
});
```